# Optimal way to extract a URL from web page loaded via XMLHTTPRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xmlhttprequest

**Problem Overview**

- I have a dynamically produced web page, `X`, which consists of search results linking to web pages, `Y1`, `Y2`, `Y3` etc.
- `Y1` contains a resource URL `R1`, `Y2` contains resource URL `R2`, and so on.
- I would like to dynamically enhance page `X` with links to resources `R1`, `R2` etc.

**Possible Solution**

I'm currently thinking of **using JavaScript and XMLHTTPRequest to retrieve the HTML** from web pages `Y1`, `Y2`, etc., and to then **use a regular expression to extract the URL**.

Pages `Y1`, `Y2`, etc. are in the region of 30-100KB HTML each.

**Does this sound like a good plan?** Or would I be better retrieving each web page in JSON format and extracting the resource URL from there? If HTML is the way to go, do you have any suggested optimisations/short cuts for searching 30-100 KB of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use regex to extract the URL. I suggest using jQuery to perform the AJAX request, and then use jQuery to parse and filter out the URLs from the HTML that is returned from the server.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://my.url.here",
    dataType: "html";
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery("a", data).each(function() {
            var $link = jQuery(this);
            ...
            ...
        });
    }
    ...
});
```

If jQuery is not an option, you can do something like this when you get your response back:

```
var html = XHR.responseText;
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;

//you can now search for nodes inside your div.
//The following gives you all the anchor tags
div.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, jQuery isn't an option. However, I like the sound of the alternative - cheers!