# Safely parse/work with HTML from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing code (right now it's a Chrome extension, though I may make it cross-browser, or try to get the site owners to include the enhancement) that works with the contents of a particular `<div>` on a webpage that the user is viewing, and any pages that are part of the same discussion thread. So I find links to the other pages of the thread, and get them with `XMLHttpRequest`. What I want to do is just be able to use `.getElementsByClassName('foo')` on the resulting page.

I know I can do that by loading the results of the request into a div (i.e. [Optimal way to extract a URL from web page loaded via XMLHTTPRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677340/optimal-way-to-extract-a-url-from-web-page-loaded-via-xmlhttprequest)). However, while figuring out the best way to do this, I read that there are security concerns ([MDN - Safely Parsing Simple HTML to DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Analyzing_and_manipulating_HTML_responseText)).

In this case, I'm not sure that matters much, since the extension would just load a page from the same comment thread that the user was already looking at, but I'd still like to do this the right way.

So what's the right way to work with HTML from an `XMLHttpRequest`?

P.S. If the best answer is jQuery, then tell me that, but I've yet to start using jQuery, and would also like to know the fundamentals here.

Edit: I don't know why I phrased things the way I did, but let me be clearer that I'm really hoping for a non-JQuery answer. I've been trying to learn the basics of javascript before learning JQuery and I'd prefer not to import a whole framework to call one function when I don't understand what I'm doing. That may seem irrational, but it's what I'm doing for the moment.

Comment: Working with a raw XHR object can be painful.  jQuery would indeed make it much simpler.  See the post, get, and ajax functions  http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=ajax&go=

Comment: jQuery is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Since you say you're not opposed to using jQuery, you should look at the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.  It loads html from the address you specify, then places it into the matched elements.  So for example

```
$("#formDiv").load("../AjaxContent/AdvSearchForm.aspx?ItemType=" + ItemType);
```

Would load the html from `../AjaxContent/AdvSearchForm.aspx` then place it in the div with the id of `formDiv`

Optional parameters exist for passing a data to the server with the request, and also a callback function.